# How can I select elements on dom (with jQuery) that has some data attribute that ends with "created"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have all my elements, on a project, that are being transferred with data attributes so the javascript can know what to do.

But I have one problem, one part of the application must get all the created variables to compare time, and I have they saved like (**data-product-created**, **data-category-created**, **data-link-created**, etc...). It would be a huge headache if I had to put them manually on the jQuery selector...

Do **jQuery** has some method to search custom data **attributes** existence?

Like: `element[data-(.*)-created]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `mVChr` answer (THANK YOU), i've rewritten the code on a simple, better and clean code:

```
jQuery('div').filter(function(){
  for( var i in this.attributes ){
    if(typeof this.attributes[i] !== 'object') continue;
    if(this.attributes[i].name.match(/data\-(.*?)\-created/)) return true;
  }
  return false;
})
```

Changes:

```
+ Verifying attribute type... some attributes are browser internal functions or callbacks.
~ Using filter handler from jQuery, its better and cleaner way.
~ Using for instead of $.each, faster indeed.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a low level Javascript method to loop through elements and pull their created values:

```
var getCreateds = function($els) {
    var returnSet = [];
    $els.each(function(i, el){
        var elDict = {'el': el};
        $.each(el.attributes, function(i, attr){
            var m = attr.name.match(/data\-(.*?)\-created/);
            if (m) elDict[m[1]] = attr.value;
        });
        returnSet.push(elDict);
    });
    return returnSet;
};
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjVaD/2/)

Comment: Good answer +1, but not the better way. I've rewritten that code on a better way, check my own answer. Thanks for your contribution! :D